# BackboneJS model method 'get' doesn't account for idAttribute setting

Tags: javascript, mongodb, backbone.js

I just added `idAttribute: '_id'` to some models in my BackboneJS app for use with MongoDB on the server-side. At first, this works as expected, when looking at the model in a view later, `this.model.id` is set to the same value as `_id`. However, if I use the `get` method on the model for `id`, it returns `undefined`. I could just switch to using `this.model.id` instead of `this.model.get('id')`, it just seemed that using the `get` method was a cleaner and more formal way of retrieving model data. Is this by design? Should I just stop using `model.get` everywhere for consistency sake? Thanks.

Comment: There's a difference between `this.model.id` and `this.model.get('id')`. `this.model.id` is "synchronized" with your `idAttribute` attribute. `this.model.get('id')` refers to `this.model.attributes.id` which doesn't exist if you're not using it. Now, the `get` method only contains `return this.attributes[attr];`. Hence it doesn't check whether you're trying to get your `idAttribute` attribute or not. The only 2 solutions are, as mentioned, using `this.model.id` or `this.model.get(this.model.idAttribute)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that you still would have to use this.model.get('_id').  Telling backbone which property uniquely identifies your model doesn't change the name of the property in the attributes hash.